# Out of Memory Exception in Android with AES Encryption

Tags: java, android, encryption

Here is my source code:

```
public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] Data) throws Exception {
    Log.i("Debug", "initial data is" + java.util.Arrays.toString(Data));

    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data);

    Log.i("Debug", "encrypted data is" + java.util.Arrays.toString(encVal));
     ;
    return Base64.encode(encVal,0);
   }
```

When the data length of the byte[] Data is around 800 kb or so, i keep on receiving.

```
     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

Can you please help me how can i change my code to avoid this issue? I had to encode with base64 to avoid the error of incomplete block in decryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well one problem is the logging you're doing - by converting the data into a string, you're probably using up to 5 characters per byte, and each character is 2 bytes, so that's 10 bytes in memory use per original byte. You're then using string concatenation, so that's doubling the amount of memory required (due to the copying).

So *just the logging statements* are each taking about 16MB I suspect. Is it really *useful* to you to have a full 800KB array logged?

What happens if you remove the log statements?

Comment: thanks i'll try to remove them, i was just logging to make sure the initial array and the decrypted array are the same.

Comment: The best way to avoid that is to use an authenticated encryption mode such as GCM (if available, try the Bouncy Castle libraries otherwise). This adds integrity of the ciphertext. Alternatively, you could log and compare a SHA-256 result over the data before and after encryption. That way you can compare without giving away the plain text (except if the plain text is identical to a previous plain text).